# $x^2+y^2+z^2=a$ then what is the of range of $xy+yz+zx$

Tags: inequality, quadratics

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=a$$ then what is the of range of $$xy+yz+zx$$ 
options

A) $[-a, a]$

B) $[-a/2, a/2]$

C) $[-a/2, a]$

Comment: Have you tried lagrange multipliers?

Answer (score 3):

since
$$a=x^2+y^2+z^2\ge xy+yz+xz$$
this is true because
$$(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(x-z)^2\ge 0$$
and the other hand,we have
$$(x+y+z)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+xz)\ge 0\Longrightarrow xy+yz+xz\ge-\dfrac{a}{2}$$
so
$$xy+yz+xz\in[-\dfrac{a}{2},a]$$

Comment: It should be mentioned that the upper and lower bounds here can actually be achieved (by making $x=y=z=\sqrt{a/3}$ and $x=0, y=\sqrt{a/2},\ z=-\sqrt{a/2}$, for instance). Otherwise, the range could be a proper subset of the interval found here.